# show all multiple solutions using a nested recursive algorithm vb.net

Tags: vb.net, recursion

My recursive isn't that good I had to add a list which contains all failed paths to exit other recursive paths quickly, could probably do it without that if it was smarter.

Anyways what I'm trying to do is every time a duplicate is detected it either drops to the next row or goes all the way to the top and tries to fill in the duplicate value only if its possible to keep the values unique. Then I get a bunch of rows all uniquely sorted. Now I coded all this properly and it works just fine.. the problem is undoing this to get back the same solution, there could be multiple answers I want to be able to list all the possible answers which are the same length as the input list.

If the bitstream contains like 2 zero's and when decoding this it can't insert 2 unique values in the row as some value is already previously used then the whole current node gets skipped as being the wrong answer.

Say I got this number

```
1 9 4 2 4 2 4 2 1 2 4 3 2 4 1 2 3 4 0 3 1 3 0 4 2 0 4 1 0 0 2 0 4 6 3 1 3
```

The Bits are 0 for unique and 1 for duplicate

```
0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1
```

The rows look like this

```
(Row 0):  1 9 4 2 3 0 
(Row 1):  4 2 1 3 0 
(Row 2):  4 2 1 0 3 
(Row 3):  2 4 3 
(Row 4):  2 4 1 
(Row 5):  2 3 4 0 
(Row 6):  4 2 0 
(Row 7):  4 1 0 2 
(Row 8):  4 6 3 1
```

All the rows combined into a single string for passing it to program

```
1 9 4 2 3 0 4 2 1 3 0 4 2 1 0 3 2 4 3 2 4 1 2 3 4 0 4 2 0 4 1 0 2 4 6 3 1
```

I run this function by pressing Button2
3 textbox's
`txtUndoPlaintext.Text = "1 9 4 2 3 0 4 2 1 3 0 4 2 1 0 3 2 4 3 2 4 1 2 3 4 0 4 2 0 4 1 0 2 4 6 3 1"`
`txtUndoBitMask.Text = "0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1"`
txtOutput (this one is multi-line) where the answers print out.

The answer I get back is

```
1 9 4 2 4 2 4 2 1 2 4 3 2 4 1 2 3 4 0 3 1 3 0 4 2 0 4 1 0 0 2 0 4 6 3 1 3
```

which checking with the original is off where its `0 2` to `2 0` on `index 30`

```
1 9 4 2 4 2 4 2 1 2 4 3 2 4 1 2 3 4 0 3 1 3 0 4 2 0 4 1 0 0 0 2 4 6 3 1 3
```

**My problem is I only get back one answer how do I get all answers back?**

**Here is my code**

```
Public bitmask() As Byte
Public FailedPaths As New List(Of String)
Public Uniques()() As Byte

Public Function GetUniquesAt(uniques()() As Byte, CurrentRow As UInteger, ProcessedBits()() As Byte) As Byte()
    Dim eachUniqueIndex As Integer = 0

    Dim UniquesUsed() As Byte
    'ReDim UniquesUsed(0)

    For eachUniqueIndex = 0 To UBound(uniques(CurrentRow), 1)
        If ProcessedBits(CurrentRow)(eachUniqueIndex) = 1 Then
            'Add a new number to this row
            If UniquesUsed Is Nothing Then
                ReDim Preserve UniquesUsed(0)
            Else
                ReDim Preserve UniquesUsed(UniquesUsed.Length)
            End If
            Dim LastValueInRow As Integer = UniquesUsed.Length
            UniquesUsed(LastValueInRow - 1) = uniques(CurrentRow)(eachUniqueIndex)
        End If
    Next

    Return UniquesUsed
End Function

Public Function GetCurrentOffsetForRow(uniques()() As Byte, CurrentRow As UInteger, ProcessedBits()() As Byte) As UInteger
    Dim eachUniqueIndex As Integer = 0

    For eachUniqueIndex = 0 To UBound(uniques(CurrentRow), 1)
        If ProcessedBits(CurrentRow)(eachUniqueIndex) = 0 Then
            Return eachUniqueIndex
        End If
    Next
    Return eachUniqueIndex
End Function

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    txtUndoPlaintext.Text = Replace(txtUndoPlaintext.Text, "  ", " ")
    txtUndoPlaintext.Text = txtUndoPlaintext.Text.TrimStart(CChar(" "))
    txtUndoPlaintext.Text = txtUndoPlaintext.Text.TrimEnd(CChar(" "))

    Dim UniqueList() As Byte = Split(txtUndoPlaintext.Text, " ").[Select](Function(n) Byte.Parse(n)).ToArray()

    txtUndoBitMask.Text = Replace(txtUndoBitMask.Text, "  ", " ")
    txtUndoBitMask.Text = txtUndoBitMask.Text.TrimStart(CChar(" "))
    txtUndoBitMask.Text = txtUndoBitMask.Text.TrimEnd(CChar(" "))

    bitmask = Split(txtUndoBitMask.Text, " ").[Select](Function(n) Byte.Parse(n)).ToArray()

    'Clear uniques from previous runs.
    Uniques = Nothing
    Dim PreviousRow As UInteger = 0

    'Check if unique exists from first row to current row
    Dim CurrentRow As UInteger = 0
    Dim ContainsValueInRow As Boolean = False

    'if uniques current row isn't initialized then initialize it.
    If Uniques Is Nothing Then
        ReDim Uniques(CurrentRow)
        Uniques(CurrentRow) = New Byte() {}
    End If

    Dim ProcessedBits()() As Byte
    ReDim ProcessedBits(CurrentRow)
    ProcessedBits(CurrentRow) = New Byte() {}

    'Load uniques up in the Uniques List
    For Each Value In UniqueList
        ContainsValueInRow = False
        'Check row if it contains the current Value if it does change to next row.
        For eachUniqueIndex = 0 To UBound(Uniques(CurrentRow), 1)
            If Uniques(CurrentRow)(eachUniqueIndex) = Value Then
                ContainsValueInRow = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next

        If ContainsValueInRow Then
            CurrentRow += 1
            ReDim Preserve Uniques(CurrentRow)
            Uniques(CurrentRow) = New Byte() {}

            ReDim Preserve ProcessedBits(CurrentRow)
            ProcessedBits(CurrentRow) = New Byte() {}
        End If

        Dim LastValueInRow As Integer = Uniques(CurrentRow).Length
        'Add new number to this row
        ReDim Preserve Uniques(CurrentRow)(LastValueInRow)
        Uniques(CurrentRow)(LastValueInRow) = Value

        ReDim Preserve ProcessedBits(CurrentRow)(LastValueInRow)
        ProcessedBits(CurrentRow)(LastValueInRow) = 0
    Next

    FailedPaths.Clear()

    CurrentRow = 0

    Dim CurrentProcessedByte As Long = 0
    Dim CurrentOffset As Long = 0
    Dim FinalString As String = ""

    Dim ExitedTooSoon As Boolean = False

    ProcessTreeNodes(FinalString, ProcessedBits, CurrentProcessedByte, PreviousRow, CurrentRow)

    Dim output As String
    output = output & "Final Decoded Answer: " & FinalString & vbCrLf
    output = output & "Stopped at row: " & CurrentRow & vbCrLf

    txtOutput.Text = txtOutput.Text & output
End Sub

Public Sub ProcessTreeNodes(_FinalString As String, _ProcessedBits()() As Byte, CurrentProcessedByte As Byte, PreviousRow As UInteger, CurrentRow As UInteger)

    'Clone Data to get rid of References, so we always copy here
    Dim ProcessedBits(_ProcessedBits.GetUpperBound(0))() As Byte
    For i = 0 To _ProcessedBits.Length - 1
        ProcessedBits(i) = _ProcessedBits(i).Clone()
    Next

    Dim FinalString As String = _FinalString.Clone()
    Dim LoopTwo As Boolean = False
    Dim ExitedTooSoon As Boolean = False
    Dim CurrentOffset As UInteger = GetCurrentOffsetForRow(Uniques, CurrentRow, ProcessedBits)

    While True
        'If finished with everything just simply exit this loop
        If bitmask.Length = CurrentProcessedByte Then Exit While

        'Unique currently on this row no need any extra processing
        If bitmask(CurrentProcessedByte) = 0 Then

            'Bad Sub Node.. exit it
            If Uniques(CurrentRow).Length = CurrentOffset Then
                ExitedTooSoon = True
                Exit While
            End If

            FinalString = FinalString & " " & Uniques(CurrentRow)(CurrentOffset)
            'Mark as processed for future calculations
            ProcessedBits(CurrentRow)(CurrentOffset) = 1
        End If

        'Switch to a new row
        If bitmask(CurrentProcessedByte) = 1 Then
            CurrentOffset = 0
            PreviousRow = CurrentRow
            'If Blank Row -> Build a next Row Or Start from Top.
            'If the row is Row 0, then next row is Row 1, but if Row 1.. then next row to check is Row 0 etc..

            If CurrentRow = 0 Then
                CurrentRow = 1
            ElseIf CurrentRow > 0 Then
                CurrentRow = 0
            End If

            Dim MainRowUniquesUsed() As Byte
            Dim CurrentRowUniques() As Byte

            'Do crazy loop checks to see whats the next value.
            While True
                If FailedPaths.Contains(FinalString) Then
                    ExitedTooSoon = True
                    Exit While
                End If

                MainRowUniquesUsed = GetUniquesAt(Uniques, PreviousRow, ProcessedBits)
                CurrentRowUniques = GetUniquesAt(Uniques, CurrentRow, ProcessedBits)
                CurrentOffset = GetCurrentOffsetForRow(Uniques, CurrentRow, ProcessedBits)

                If LoopTwo Then
                    'Get a list of all Rows used +1
                    Dim listsOfUniquesUsed As New List(Of Byte())
                    Dim LastRow As Long = 0
                    Dim IsPossible As Boolean = True
                    For row As Long = 0 To ProcessedBits.Length - 1
                        'Get a list of every value used in every row

                        'Don't process the tree until at least 2 rows are used.. then it will use the 3rd row if possible
                        If ProcessedBits.Length > 1 AndAlso ProcessedBits(1)(0) = 0 Then
                            Exit For
                        End If
                        If ProcessedBits(row)(0) = 1 Then
                            listsOfUniquesUsed.Add(GetUniquesAt(Uniques, row, ProcessedBits))
                            'Get the first value of a un-used Row just to checking if it's a possible answer too.
                        ElseIf ProcessedBits(row)(0) = 0 Then
                            listsOfUniquesUsed.Add(New Byte() {Uniques(row)(0)})
                            LastRow = row
                            Exit For
                        End If
                        'Hit last row and last row is already used so this whole thing is not possible
                        If row = ProcessedBits.Length - 1 AndAlso ProcessedBits(row)(0) = 1 Then
                            IsPossible = False
                        End If
                    Next

                    If IsPossible Then
                        'This checks to make sure all the commons that are partially in all lists.
                        Dim list() As Byte = listsOfUniquesUsed.SelectMany(Function(x) x).Distinct().Where(Function(item) listsOfUniquesUsed.All(Function(l) l.Contains(item))).ToArray()

                        'If a possible match is found 
                        'make sure there Is a row below the current row, If no point in doing it.
                        'If list.Count > 0 AndAlso PreviousRow + 1 < Uniques.Length AndAlso FailedPaths.Where(Function(c) c.StartsWith(FinalString)).Count = 0 Then
                        If list.Count > 0 AndAlso PreviousRow + 1 < Uniques.Length AndAlso Not FailedPaths.Contains(FinalString) Then
                            'CurrentOffset Spoofed
                            Dim PreviousRowSpoofed As UInteger = CurrentRow
                            Dim CurrentRowSpoofed As UInteger = LastRow

                            'Possible 2 answers are possible!
                            ProcessTreeNodes(FinalString, ProcessedBits, CurrentProcessedByte, PreviousRowSpoofed, CurrentRowSpoofed)
                        End If
                    End If
                End If

                'Quick fix
                If MainRowUniquesUsed Is Nothing Then
                    CurrentRow = PreviousRow
                    CurrentOffset = GetCurrentOffsetForRow(Uniques, CurrentRow, ProcessedBits)
                    FinalString = FinalString & " " & Uniques(CurrentRow)(CurrentOffset)
                    'Mark as processed for future calculations
                    ProcessedBits(CurrentRow)(CurrentOffset) = 1
                    LoopTwo = True
                    Exit While
                End If

                'Next Row is blank, then its just a fresh entry
                If CurrentRowUniques Is Nothing Then
                    FinalString = FinalString & " " & Uniques(CurrentRow)(CurrentOffset)
                    'Mark as processed for future calculations
                    ProcessedBits(CurrentRow)(CurrentOffset) = 1
                    LoopTwo = True
                    Exit While
                    'Scan this row if its a possible insert here or possible go to next
                ElseIf CurrentRowUniques IsNot Nothing Then
                    Dim ValueNotUsed() As Byte = Uniques(CurrentRow) _
                    .Select(Function(item, index) New With {.Item = item, .Index = index}) _
                    .Where(Function(x) ProcessedBits(CurrentRow)(x.Index) = 0) _
                    .Select(Function(x) x.Item).ToArray()

                    'If no values are possible, then go check next row.
                    If ValueNotUsed.Length = 0 Then
                        'If the Next Row is the Row we were in, just before this one Jump 2 rows
                        If CurrentRow + 1 = PreviousRow Then
                            CurrentRow = CurrentRow + 2
                        Else
                            CurrentRow = CurrentRow + 1
                        End If
                        'This quick fix isn't checked could be wrong
                        'it just starts from the top if it hit a row past the last row.
                        If CurrentRow >= Uniques.Length Then
                            CurrentRow = 0
                        End If
                        Continue While
                        'This is a possible answer area (where it would spawn multiple nodes to keep recursively finishing it.)
                    ElseIf ValueNotUsed.Length > 0 Then
                        If Not MainRowUniquesUsed.Contains(ValueNotUsed(0)) Then
                            'The next pattern isn't found in this Row, so we hope next row.
                            'Keep hopping rows until we hit the row which is the farthest one
                            'Then we could exit out.
                            'If the Next Row is the Row we were in, just before this one Jump 2 rows

                            If CurrentRow + 1 = PreviousRow Then
                                CurrentRow = CurrentRow + 2
                            Else
                                CurrentRow = CurrentRow + 1
                            End If

                            If CurrentRow + 1 > PreviousRow Then
                                'Hit the row we currently on and still no match so its a bad loop
                                ExitedTooSoon = True
                                Exit While
                            ElseIf CurrentRow >= Uniques.Length Then
                                'Probably does not work?
                                CurrentRow = 0
                            End If
                            Continue While
                        End If
                        'Scan Previous Rows for the same answer as in this Row.
                        FinalString = FinalString & " " & Uniques(CurrentRow)(CurrentOffset)
                        'Mark as processed for future calculations
                        ProcessedBits(CurrentRow)(CurrentOffset) = 1
                        LoopTwo = True
                        Exit While
                    End If
                End If
            End While
        End If

        If ExitedTooSoon Then
            Exit While
        End If

        CurrentOffset += 1
        CurrentProcessedByte += 1
    End While

    If ExitedTooSoon Then
        FailedPaths.Add(FinalString)
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim output As String
    output = output & "TreeNode Decoded Answer: " & FinalString & vbCrLf
    output = output & "Stopped at row: " & CurrentRow & vbCrLf

    txtOutput.Text = txtOutput.Text & output
End Sub
```

If you need the value generator here it is I made and I have no problem with it.
(can't post it in this question as it exceeds the size limit)
https://pastebin.com/raw/0y2DnRhi

Comment: There's really way too much code there. You really ought to be able to narrow down the issue more than that before posting a question here.

Comment: thats the thing its a logic problem that affects the whole thing I can't figure out where to add another loop so it prints out multiple solutions. I guess I'll keep working on it until I figure it out then.

Comment: You start off with a long string and then show another long string that supposedly represents the uniqueness.  Then we find out that that initial string was build by combining several rows of some table for _the purpose of processing_ by your code.  Then you present a code dump that you expect us derive the logic rules from, yet you admit it does not work as you want.  If you want any hope of getting constructive feedback, clearly state the logic rules along with sample input and expected output.

Comment: ok sorry i'll edit it tommorrow

Comment: Maybe write it differently with clear input and output that you are expecting. I'm having a hard time reading this :(

Answer (score 0):

Actually, It gets all the answers (I Hope) at least it gets the right answer and the second right answer I found with the previous code.

But some answers it finds are not even right, so it's not really a good answer. Here is the code anyways anyone wishes to modify it to work better please go ahead.

Original Answer:

```
1 9 4 2 4 2 4 2 1 2 4 3 2 4 1 2 3 4 0 3 1 3 0 4 2 0 4 1 0 0 2 0 4 6 3 1 3
```

Finds these correct answers

```
1 9 4 2 4 2 4 2 1 2 4 3 2 4 1 2 3 4 0 3 1 3 0 4 2 0 4 1 0 0 0 2 4 6 3 1 3
1 9 4 2 4 2 4 2 1 2 4 3 2 4 1 2 3 4 0 3 1 3 0 4 2 0 4 1 0 0 2 0 4 6 3 1 3
1 9 4 2 4 2 4 2 1 2 4 3 2 4 1 2 3 4 0 3 1 3 0 4 2 0 4 1 0 2 0 0 4 6 3 1 3

1 9 4 2 4 2 4 2 1 2 4 3 2 4 1 2 3 4 0 3 4 2 0 4 1 0 1 3 0 0 0 2 4 6 3 1 3
1 9 4 2 4 2 4 2 1 2 4 3 2 4 1 2 3 4 0 3 4 2 0 4 1 0 1 3 0 0 2 0 4 6 3 1 3
1 9 4 2 4 2 4 2 1 2 4 3 2 4 1 2 3 4 0 3 4 2 0 4 1 0 1 3 0 2 0 0 4 6 3 1 3
```

Finds these wrong answers too

```
1 9 4 2 4 2 4 2 1 2 4 3 2 4 1 2 3 4 0 3 4 2 0 1 3 0 4 1 0 0 0 2 4 6 3 1 3
1 9 4 2 4 2 4 2 1 2 4 3 2 4 1 2 3 4 0 3 4 2 0 1 3 0 4 1 0 0 2 0 4 6 3 1 3
1 9 4 2 4 2 4 2 1 2 4 3 2 4 1 2 3 4 0 3 4 2 0 1 3 0 4 1 0 2 0 0 4 6 3 1 3
```

I guess the wrong answers could also be possible in some way.. so I guess there is no way to avoid it.

```
'New algorithm

Private Sub Button5_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
    txtUndoPlaintext.Text = Replace(txtUndoPlaintext.Text, "  ", " ")
    txtUndoPlaintext.Text = txtUndoPlaintext.Text.TrimStart(CChar(" "))
    txtUndoPlaintext.Text = txtUndoPlaintext.Text.TrimEnd(CChar(" "))

    Dim UniqueList() As Byte = Split(txtUndoPlaintext.Text, " ").[Select](Function(n) Byte.Parse(n)).ToArray()

    txtUndoBitMask.Text = Replace(txtUndoBitMask.Text, "  ", " ")
    txtUndoBitMask.Text = txtUndoBitMask.Text.TrimStart(CChar(" "))
    txtUndoBitMask.Text = txtUndoBitMask.Text.TrimEnd(CChar(" "))

    bitmask = Split(txtUndoBitMask.Text, " ").[Select](Function(n) Byte.Parse(n)).ToArray()

    'Clear uniques from previous runs.
    Uniques = Nothing
    Dim PreviousRow As UInteger = 0

    'Check if unique exists from first row to current row
    Dim CurrentRow As UInteger = 0
    Dim ContainsValueInRow As Boolean = False

    'if uniques current row isn't initialized then initialize it.
    If Uniques Is Nothing Then
        ReDim Uniques(CurrentRow)
        Uniques(CurrentRow) = New Byte() {}
    End If

    Dim ProcessedBits()() As Byte
    ReDim ProcessedBits(CurrentRow)
    ProcessedBits(CurrentRow) = New Byte() {}

    'Load uniques up in the Uniques List
    For Each Value In UniqueList
        ContainsValueInRow = False
        'Check row if it contains the current Value if it does change to next row.
        For eachUniqueIndex = 0 To UBound(Uniques(CurrentRow), 1)
            If Uniques(CurrentRow)(eachUniqueIndex) = Value Then
                ContainsValueInRow = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next

        If ContainsValueInRow Then
            CurrentRow += 1
            ReDim Preserve Uniques(CurrentRow)
            Uniques(CurrentRow) = New Byte() {}

            ReDim Preserve ProcessedBits(CurrentRow)
            ProcessedBits(CurrentRow) = New Byte() {}
        End If

        Dim LastValueInRow As Integer = Uniques(CurrentRow).Length
        'Add new number to this row
        ReDim Preserve Uniques(CurrentRow)(LastValueInRow)
        Uniques(CurrentRow)(LastValueInRow) = Value

        ReDim Preserve ProcessedBits(CurrentRow)(LastValueInRow)
        ProcessedBits(CurrentRow)(LastValueInRow) = 0
    Next

    FailedPaths.Clear()

    CurrentRow = 0

    Dim CurrentProcessedByte As Long = 0
    Dim CurrentOffset As Long = 0
    Dim FinalString As String = ""

    Dim ExitedTooSoon As Boolean = False

    Process(FinalString, ProcessedBits, CurrentProcessedByte, PreviousRow, CurrentRow)

    Dim output As String
    output = output & "Final Decoded Answer: " & FinalString & vbCrLf
    output = output & "Stopped at row: " & CurrentRow & vbCrLf

    txtOutput.Text = txtOutput.Text & output
End Sub


Public Sub Process(_FinalString As String, _ProcessedBits()() As Byte, CurrentProcessedByte As Byte, PreviousRow As UInteger, CurrentRow As UInteger)

    'Clone Data to get rid of References, so we always copy here
    Dim ProcessedBits(_ProcessedBits.GetUpperBound(0))() As Byte
    For i = 0 To _ProcessedBits.Length - 1
        ProcessedBits(i) = _ProcessedBits(i).Clone()
    Next

    Dim FinalString As String = _FinalString.Clone()
    Dim LoopTwo As Boolean = False
    Dim ExitedTooSoon As Boolean = False
    Dim CurrentOffset As UInteger = GetCurrentOffsetForRow(Uniques, CurrentRow, ProcessedBits)

    Dim solutionsRows As New List(Of UInteger)

    While True
        'If finished with everything just simply exit this loop
        If bitmask.Length = CurrentProcessedByte Then Exit While

        'Unique currently on this row no need any extra processing
        If bitmask(CurrentProcessedByte) = 0 Then

            'Bad Sub Node.. exit it
            If Uniques(CurrentRow).Length = CurrentOffset Then
                ExitedTooSoon = True
                Exit While
            End If

            FinalString = FinalString & " " & Uniques(CurrentRow)(CurrentOffset)
            'Mark as processed for future calculations
            ProcessedBits(CurrentRow)(CurrentOffset) = 1
        End If

        'Switch to a new row
        If bitmask(CurrentProcessedByte) = 1 Then

            'Get all possible solutions first
            solutionsRows.Clear()

            PreviousRow = CurrentRow
            Dim MainRowUniquesUsed() As Byte

            MainRowUniquesUsed = GetUniquesAt(Uniques, PreviousRow, ProcessedBits)
            CurrentRow = 0

            If LoopTwo Then
                'Get all the right value each row solutions

                Dim LastRowUsed As Boolean = False

                While True
                    If CurrentRow >= Uniques.Length Then Exit While

                    'Is Row accessible, like does the row come after a row that was used previously.
                    If ProcessedBits(CurrentRow)(0) = 1 OrElse ((CurrentRow - 1 >= 0) AndAlso ProcessedBits(CurrentRow - 1)(0) = 1) Then
                        LastRowUsed = True
                    End If

                    If LastRowUsed Then
                        Dim ValueNotUsed() As Byte = Uniques(CurrentRow) _
                        .Select(Function(item, index) New With {.Item = item, .Index = index}) _
                        .Where(Function(x) ProcessedBits(CurrentRow)(x.Index) = 0) _
                        .Select(Function(x) x.Item).ToArray()

                        If ValueNotUsed.Length > 0 AndAlso MainRowUniquesUsed.Contains(ValueNotUsed(0)) Then
                            solutionsRows.Add(CurrentRow)
                        End If
                    End If
                    'Row incrementer
                    If CurrentRow + 1 = PreviousRow Then
                        CurrentRow = CurrentRow + 2
                    Else
                        CurrentRow = CurrentRow + 1
                    End If
                    LastRowUsed = False
                End While

                CurrentRow = 0

                'Run sub-nodes on every possible solution.
                For Each Row In solutionsRows
                    Dim PreviousRowSpoofed As UInteger = PreviousRow
                    Dim CurrentRowSpoofed As UInteger = Row
                    Process(FinalString, ProcessedBits, CurrentProcessedByte, PreviousRowSpoofed, CurrentRowSpoofed)
                Next
            End If
            Dim CurrentRowUniques() As Byte

            While True
                MainRowUniquesUsed = GetUniquesAt(Uniques, PreviousRow, ProcessedBits)

                If (PreviousRow = CurrentRow) AndAlso CurrentRow = 0 Then
                    CurrentRow = 1
                ElseIf (PreviousRow = CurrentRow) AndAlso CurrentRow > 0 Then
                    CurrentRow = 0
                End If

                CurrentRowUniques = GetUniquesAt(Uniques, CurrentRow, ProcessedBits)
                CurrentOffset = GetCurrentOffsetForRow(Uniques, CurrentRow, ProcessedBits)

                'Quick fix
                If MainRowUniquesUsed Is Nothing Then
                    CurrentRow = PreviousRow
                    CurrentOffset = GetCurrentOffsetForRow(Uniques, CurrentRow, ProcessedBits)
                    FinalString = FinalString & " " & Uniques(CurrentRow)(CurrentOffset)
                    'Mark as processed for future calculations
                    ProcessedBits(CurrentRow)(CurrentOffset) = 1
                    LoopTwo = True
                    Exit While
                End If
                'Next Row is blank, then its just a fresh entry
                If CurrentRowUniques Is Nothing Then
                    FinalString = FinalString & " " & Uniques(CurrentRow)(CurrentOffset)
                    'Mark as processed for future calculations
                    ProcessedBits(CurrentRow)(CurrentOffset) = 1
                    LoopTwo = True
                    Exit While
                    'Scan this row if its a possible insert here or possible go to next
                End If
                If CurrentRowUniques IsNot Nothing Then
                    Dim ValueNotUsed() As Byte = Uniques(CurrentRow) _
                    .Select(Function(item, index) New With {.Item = item, .Index = index}) _
                    .Where(Function(x) ProcessedBits(CurrentRow)(x.Index) = 0) _
                    .Select(Function(x) x.Item).ToArray()

                    'If no values are possible, then go check next row.
                    If ValueNotUsed.Length = 0 Then
                        'If the Next Row is the Row we were in, just before this one Jump 2 rows
                        If CurrentRow + 1 = PreviousRow Then
                            CurrentRow = CurrentRow + 2
                        Else
                            CurrentRow = CurrentRow + 1
                        End If
                        'This quick fix isn't checked could be wrong
                        'it just starts from the top if it hit a row past the last row.
                        If CurrentRow >= Uniques.Length Then
                            ExitedTooSoon = True
                            Exit While
                        End If
                        Continue While
                        'This is a possible answer area (where it would spawn multiple nodes to keep recursively finishing it.)
                    ElseIf ValueNotUsed.Length > 0 Then
                        If Not MainRowUniquesUsed.Contains(ValueNotUsed(0)) Then
                            'The next pattern isn't found in this Row, so we hope next row.
                            'Keep hopping rows until we hit the row which is the farthest one
                            'Then we could exit out.
                            'If the Next Row is the Row we were in, just before this one Jump 2 rows

                            If CurrentRow + 1 = PreviousRow Then
                                CurrentRow = CurrentRow + 2
                            Else
                                CurrentRow = CurrentRow + 1
                            End If

                            If CurrentRow + 1 > PreviousRow Then
                                'Hit the row we currently on and still no match so its a bad loop
                                ExitedTooSoon = True
                                Exit While
                            ElseIf CurrentRow >= Uniques.Length Then
                                ExitedTooSoon = True
                                Exit While
                            End If
                            Continue While
                        End If
                        'Scan Previous Rows for the same answer as in this Row.
                        FinalString = FinalString & " " & Uniques(CurrentRow)(CurrentOffset)
                        'Mark as processed for future calculations
                        ProcessedBits(CurrentRow)(CurrentOffset) = 1
                        LoopTwo = True
                        Exit While
                    End If
                End If
                If FailedPaths.Contains(FinalString) Then
                    ExitedTooSoon = True
                    Exit While
                End If
            End While
        End If
        If ExitedTooSoon Then
            Exit While
        End If

        CurrentOffset += 1
        CurrentProcessedByte += 1
    End While

    If ExitedTooSoon Then
        FailedPaths.Add(FinalString)
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim output As String
    output = output & "TreeNode Decoded Answer: " & FinalString & vbCrLf
    output = output & "Stopped at row: " & CurrentRow & vbCrLf

    txtOutput.Text = txtOutput.Text & output
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply make a array to hold your solutions then loop each one to create a new call to the same data like so

```
        For Each Row In solutionsRows
            Process(FinalString, ProcessedBits, CurrentProcessedByte, PreviousRow, Row)
        Next
```